# the shared object name conflicts

Tags: linux, boost, shared-libraries

My app links libboost_python (version: 1.46.1) in host A (OS: Ubuntu 11.04). The library is built from source and its info is as follows:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 henry henry      25 2011-11-10 14:33 libboost_python.so -> libboost_python.so.1.46.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 henry henry  379867 2011-11-10 14:33 libboost_python.so.1.46.1
```

When I run my app on host B (OS: Ubuntu 11.10), I install libboost_python with the same version with apt.  Its info is a little different:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     30 2011-06-03 14:54 /usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so -> libboost_python-py27.so.1.46.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 291224 2011-06-03 14:54 /usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so.1.46.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 2011-11-09 04:34 /usr/lib/libboost_python.so -> libboost_python-py27.so
```

The eventual target linked by libboost_python.so is different (host B has a 'py27').  So when I run my app, an error occurs:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_python.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this conflicted name? 
the output when i run cmd 'readelf -d myapp':

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libboost_python.so.1.46.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.46.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpython2.7.so.1.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libjuserclass.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
```

the curious thing is that the entry for boost doesn't save so-name but the full name of the lib.

Comment: BTW, you should accept some answers to your questions. Stops them appearing as unanswered questions, and shows some courtesy to the people who cared to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here: The clean one (recompile against the new naming scheme) and the dirty one (make a link representation of the old library).

The Ubuntu maintainers (and possibly the upstream) have considered it wise to include the python version in the boost_python libraries' version. You need to have linked against the right python version of libboost_python, and the name "libboost_python-py27.so.1.46.1" makes sure of that. You might have linked against Python 2.6 on your devel machine and never realized it until your program crashed. You should relink your program against the newer version of the `libboost-python1.46-dev` package that is shipped with Ubuntu 11.10. Either completely upgrade your devel machine to a newer Ubuntu or selectively pull out the new version of `libboost-python1.46-dev`.

The dirty fix is a little quicker:

```
user@B> sudo ln -s libboost_python-py27.so.1.46.1 libboost_python.so.1.46.1
```

Edit: It is perfectly right for the versioned name of the libraries to appear in the linked executable. The reason is simple: You can have multiple versionss of libboost installed on your system, with some programs linked e.g. against 1.46.1 and some against 1.47.1. The non-versioned name of the .so file is for the linker during compilation stage and linked to the same version as the installed headers of boost. After compilation, only the versioned .so's are necessary.

Comment: thanks thiton. I have another question about the so-name as i said above. do you know why?